# 2-in-1 phablet/laptop - detachable keyboard, long battery life, 3G/4G sim slot

Tags: laptop, smartphones, tablet, 4g, detachable

Those are the requirements:

1. Sim slot for mobile broadband
2. Detachable keyboard, preferably with additional battery
3. Good for multimedia/surfing
4. Weight in tablet config so that woman can hold it for a while without dropping it

Idea is to give my wife all-round device that can replace a laptop but will also be easy to pack into a bag and take outdoors for a few hours. I'm UK based so thinking on packing into it Three all-you-can-eat-data sim for mobile phones (not mobile broadband) for cheap internet-on-the-move.

Used item is perfectly fine, so please do not limit yourselves to 2016/2017 models. Price is a factor, but with used item not so much, so let's say £500 is the limit.

I'm perfectly willing to experiment, so chinese slates are ok, too.

I'm having serious problem finding something that will match all criteria, not to mention also reasonably priced. I'm happy to have another look myself if someone points me to a search engine that will reliably filter offers. A lot of sellers will drop a gem like "4G ready" or "Mobile internet compatible" in the description or specs, which means it will work with a dongle, but that's what will not work for me for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after another bout with search engines I had a stroke of luck and found this:

[Acer Aspire Switch 10 V Slim Aluminium Detachable 2-in-1 laptop](https://www.saveonlaptops.co.uk/NT.G5YEK.002-Acer-Aspire-Switch-10-V-Slim-Aluminium-D_2076034.html)

with various discounts and offers it was for £200.

From what I'm able to see this gadget is designed so that it can be used as a phone, so while no one will actually use it as one, it meets all the requirements with style.

My wife loves it. She would prefer it pink, obviously, but silver brushed aluminium is the next best thing.

Also this is HD display model, which works better from battery life perspective,  but in case this is important, the Switch 10V line has several models, including one with FHD display.

Specifications, in case one would be interested and/or the link goes dead:

```
Processor           Intel Atom x5-Z8300 Quad Core (1.44GHz, 2MB Cache, Burst to 1.84GHz)
Screen              10.1" (1280x720 HD Resolution)
Operating System    Microsoft Windows 10 Home 32-bit
RAM                 2GB
Solid State Drive   32GB
Storage Hard Drive  Not Included - 32GB eMMC
Optical Drive       Not Included (Designed To Be Thin & Light) - External Optical Drive Available Seperately for £29.99
Graphics            Integrated (Intel HD Graphics) 
Wireless LAN        Wireless (802.11b/g/n Wireless) 
Bluetooth           Bluetooth 4.0 
Integrated Webcam   Integrated Dual Webcam with Microphone (2MP Front, 5MP Back)
Card Reader         Micro SD Slot 
USB Ports           1x USB 3.1 Type C, 1x USB 2.0 (in Keyboard)
Speakers            Integrated Sound System 
Charge Time         2.5 Hours 
HDMI Port           1x Micro HDMI 
Warranty            Acer 12 Months Collect & Return Warranty 
Battery Life        7-8 Hours (up to 8 hours with power management)
Weight              1-2 Kg (This Model 1.15 Kg)
Product Type        Convertible 
Keyboard Type       Laptop Keyboard Detachable
3G                  Integrated 3G Module (Supports LTE/4G)
Colour              Grey
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider the [Microsoft Surface 3 LTE](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/devices/surface-3). I have one myself, and really like it. I specifically purchased it for it's built-in LTE capability, because I find looping WiFi through a phone or using a dongle awkward. Unfortunately, Surface 3 is no longer available direct from Microsoft - I don't know what the other options in your area are. You mentioned that refurbished or secondary market options are acceptable, so that would be your best bet anyway.

The other key feature is the fact that it runs a real OS, not limited portable-specific OS (like Android or iOS). I wanted to be able to run proper Microsoft Office applications on it, including VBA-scripted macros, which is something the portable versions of applications could not do.

There is a keyboard and pen available. I recommend one or the other, if not both. The keyboard and it's touchpad are surprisingly good for their thinness, and the pen is very nice for when you're walking around holding it in-hand.

I've included the specs here, just in case they drop it from the website, too. If at all possible, you'll want to get the 4 GB RAM/128 GB SSD version:

- Dimensions: 10.52 x 7.36 x 0.34 in (267 x 187 x 8.7 mm), 1.37 lbs. (622g)
- Display: 10.8” 1920 x 1280 (214 PPI) 3:2 aspect ratio 10-point multi-touch
- Memory & Storage: 2GB RAM with 64GB storage, 4GB RAM with 128GB storage
- Processor: Quad Core Intel Atom™ x7-Z8700 with Intel HD Graphics
- Sensors: Ambient light sensor, Proximity sensor, Accelerometer, Gyroscope, Magnetometer, GPS in LTE-enabled models
- Ports: Full-size USB 3.0, Mini DisplayPort, Micro SD card reader, Micro USB charging port, Headset jack
- Camera: 3.5MP front-facing, 8.0MP rear-facing camera with autofocus, with 1080p HD video recording
- Battery: Up to 10 hours of video playback
- Audio: Microphone & Speakers built-in
- WiFi: 802.11ac Wi-Fi wireless networking; IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n compatible, Bluetooth 4.0 wireless technology
- LTE: Unlocked SIM (non-AT&T): UMTS/HSPA/HSPA+: 850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz
  4G LTE: 700 (Band 17), 800 (Band 20), 850 (Band 5), 1700 (Band 4), 1800 (Band 3), 1900 (Band 2), 2100 (Band 1), 2600 (Band 7) MHz
  oth 4.0

Comment: Yes, that was one of the choices I've looked at, but faulty search conditions did not showed good suggestions for mobile data version. Also, I chose Acer Switch 10V due to excellent price for new unit, but your suggestion would be actually near the top. Unfortunately, this machine sells at the moment for nearly triple the price I paid for Acer. Unless looking for used, but it still is pricey compared to Acer.

Comment: Yeah, secondary market (used/refurbished) is the only option for Surface 3 now. Sadly, Microsoft declined to put LTE in any of the later offerings.